# How can I replace multiple strings in a vector using variables and not hard coding the pattern using str_replace_all in R?

Tags: r, str-replace

I have the following vector and data frame:

```
v <- c(1:20)
df <- data.frame(CHR=c(1:23), val=sample(100, 23, replace=TRUE))
```

and I want to create the following vector:

```
v2 <- c(as.character(v), "X", "Y", "Z")
```

In my real code the length of the vector and df will differ, so I am trying to create the v2 character vector using str_replace_all like so:

```
v2 <- str_replace_all(as.character(df$CHR), c(as.character(length(v) + 1) = "X", as.character(length(v) + 2) = "Y"), as.character(length(v) + 3) = "Z"))
```

However this throws an error "unexpected '=' in "labels <- str_replace_all(as.character(df$CHR), c(as.character(length(v) + 1) =""

I thought I was using str_replace_all correctly. If I simply run:

```
labels <- str_replace_all(as.character(df$CHR), c("21" = "X", "22" = "Y", "23" = "Z"))
```

I get the correct result but I don't want to hard code.

If my code evaluates to the same string pattern, why doesn't it work? please let me know if you can help.

Comment: What I really want to do is use the df CHR column, turn it into a character vector, and have the last 3 characters be "X","Y","M" instead of the original numbers. I am also curious why my code with str_replace_all didn't work

Answer (score 2):

We may use `setNames` to create the named vector instead of passing an expression on the lhs of `=`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(as.character(df$CHR), 
       setNames(c("X", "Y", "Z"), length(v) + 1:3))
```

-output

```
[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "X" 
[22] "Y"  "Z"
```

---

If we want to use expression on the lhs, use `:=` operator

```
library(dplyr)
dplyr::lst(!!as.character(length(v) + 1) := "X", 
    !!as.character(length(v) + 2) := "Y", !!as.character(length(v) + 3) := "Z")
$`21`
[1] "X"

$`22`
[1] "Y"

$`23`
[1] "Z"
```

and then use it as

```
str_replace_all(as.character(df$CHR), 
   unlist(dplyr::lst(!!as.character(length(v) + 1) := "X", 
   !!as.character(length(v) + 2) := "Y",
   !!as.character(length(v) + 3) := "Z")))
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "X"  "Y"  "Z"
```

Comment: Thank you! What is the purpose / necessity of the " !! " operator?

Comment: @David_G It is a bang-bang operator to evaluate the expression on the lhs of `:=`.  Generally, we evaluate expression on the rhs of `=`

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** without hard coding:

```
v2 <- c(intersect(v, df$CHR), LETTERS[(dim(df)[1]+1):26])
```

**First answer:** Maybe this one?

```
v2 <- c(intersect(v, df$CHR), LETTERS[24:26])
```

```
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8" 
 [9] "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16"
[17] "17" "18" "19" "20" "X"  "Y"  "Z"
```